# Unable to satisfy all prerequisites for setup

Tags: installation, setup-project, prerequisites

I made setup project for C# application from Visual Studio 2008. My motive of creating this setup is that I just want to give exe file to client and at clients place this setup should install all prerequisites for running the setup smoothly like .net framework sql server express edition etc. So for that I selected all the prerequisites by right clicking the setup project and double clicking the Prerequisites button. But when I am running this setup on other PC. The setup file is not running because of two error:

> 1) Unable to satisfy all prerequisites for setup setup cannot continue
>   until all system components have been successfully install.
>
> Details:
>
> Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2005 Express
>   Edition SP2(x86) failed with following error message. "This version of
>   SQL Server 2005 Express edition is not supported for the current
>   processor architecture"
>
> 2) Communication port doesn't exist.

Now what should I include in my setup project. I don't want to give all this headache to the client.

These are the prerequisites I selected
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the SQL version isn't supported on the current processor architecture. That implies that you are trying to install it on a 64-bit system, and it's not supported. The communication port issue might be a downstream result of the first error, so I'd ignore it until you've addressed the SQL issue.

You are using really old tools that may not be supported any more. You could be more up-to-date by using the free Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, and after installing that you can add the installer project add-on to build your setup, which will have more recent versions of prerequisites.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9/view/Discussions/4

Comment: I want to make my setup suitable for all kind of computer architecture. because some client might have latest version and some may have older version. Setup should be compatible to every computer. By following above procedure my setup will run on every processor architecture???

Comment: In that case you're likely to come across many other issues, and you're basically asking the community how to install and run applications on versions of Windows that are no longer supported and with a Visual Studio version that is no longer supported.  By definition that means that old software will not work on new OS versions because Microsoft no longer maintains compatibility.